# C# 7.0 Pattern matching mixed with new out parameter

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I aim to parse and print an incoming variable with the help of *Pattern* *matching* and new *out* variable in c# 7.0. However, the method complains on uninitialized local variable 'i'. Not sure where I am going wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "23";
    Print(input);
}

static void Print(object o)
{            
    if (o is int || (o is string && int.TryParse((string)o, out int i)))
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());            
}
```

Comment: `i` is unknown if `o` is an `int`.

Comment: This can be a good tricky C# interview question.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza: Well it would be a tricky C# interview question, but I don't think it would be a good predictor of how effective the candidate is with C#. I could list all kinds of edge cases where the language might behave in an unexpected way, but that would only be good for hiring people with a very particular knowledge of C#... not necessarily people who are good at writing code. I'm not saying in-depth knowledge of C# is a bad thing (that would be a *very* odd thing to say) - I'm just saying it's not great for interviews.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, C# has been around for many years and C# 7 has only been released for a few months. I wouldn't put it past even the most capable of programmers to not be quite so intimately familiar with it yet, but that doesn't mean they can't hash out some really cool code otherwise.

Comment: @Maarten, That was the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is not ensured to be set. If `o is int` is `true`, the second part of the `if` isn't executed.

You have to assign `i` in the first condition too:

```
if (o is int i || (o is string s && int.TryParse(s, out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: How would you do that? (combining in one?)

Comment: No, I mean using two different cases in one switch: `case int i: return i.ToString(); case string x when int.TryParse(x, out int i): return i.ToString();`

Comment: That's definitely cleaner, yes.

Comment: Am I missing something? I get a malformed expression with `o is int i`?

Comment: @JohnG You are sure you have C# 7?

Comment: This is my first exercise with pattern matching and out. So sorry for anything dump. Given 'If' block, I have first Boolean condition which will fail in this scenario. Therefore, the second expression will be evaluated for a possible true/false output. In the second evaluation, I have two Boolean statements, one which first check whether o is string. If it succeed then it move on to second which is a new out implementation in c#. Question is: if I have a three independent Boolean static expression then why these expression need to be related. I am confused sorry.

Comment: No I am using an older version... Thank you!

Comment: @Nair If the first part of the `if` results in `true`, the last part isn't executed. Hence, there is no `i` then.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Got it. Perfect. This is not an odd try.  I have similar type matching and parsing in existing code base and I wanted to understand how current code base could be consized if at all we decided to move to c# 7.